# Free video editor for splitting, trimming & joining videos?

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing

I want a video editor which can easily cut a small portion of a large video, & be able to replace that portion with a clip of my choice. 
& I want to be able to preview it, before finally saving it.
Is there any software to do this?

I had been using Freemake video converter till some days & was happy with it.
But ever since i heard it installs opencandy Ive stopped using it.

I'd be thankful if someone could help me on this please.

If there is no such software, can anyone help me with your suggestions for a free video editor, capable of trimming, splitting & joining files? Something that is easy to use like freemake. Please.

( I use Win 10 )

Answer (score 2):

MS discontinued their list of 'Essentials' programs on 10 Jan 2017, but the [download link is still available here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=255475) and Movie Maker can still be installed and used.<sup>*</sup>

It does a decent job video editing, and IMO is easy to use.

<sup>* Based on [information](http://www.pcmweb.nl/nieuws/definitief-einde-voor-windows-essentials.html) from 9 Jan 2017, and not verified, because I already have it installed</sup>

Comment: I cannot get to that link (June 2019)